# Failed solution from "How to redirect stdout and stderr to a file and display stderr to console"

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, stderr, tee

First, please refer to [How to redirect stdout and stderr to a file and display stderr to console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79996/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-and-display-stderr-to-console)

This solution worked wonders for me.  I invoked both scripts and commands as the command passed to bash -c.  I even put wrote a global macro/function to make it easy to use (and avoid any typos or transpositions in the redirections).  I happily used it many, many times.

Then I wrapped the magic invocation around

```
nice make -k -j 1 configure-host
```

to start an build/install prepared by autotools.  **No make output was collected.**  In fact, each of the 3 make jobs (configure-host, all, install) put just 2 characters each into my log file.

Each outputfile consisted of 2 characters: an ascii zero and a return (0x300a).  There should have been lines and lines generated by make.

I've been puzzling my head but don't see what's happening.  Three relevant points:

1. I'm running MSYS2 / MinGW-W64 (32 bit XP).
2. *make* invokes autotools scripts that do lots of redirection using at least 6 FDs.
3. The *../configure* part of autotools does fine.

When I fall back to simple redirection

```
nice  make -k -j 1 configure-host &>logfile
```

I collect lots of both stdout and stderr together in the logfile (with a quiet terminal).

---

Here is my macro:

```
CAPTURELOG () {
  log=$1; shift; rm -f ${LOGS}/${log}.log;
  bash -c "$@" 2>&1 >>$LOGS/${log}.log | tee --append $LOGS/${log}.log; }
```

Here is it's invocation:

```
export LOGS=/g/GNU-GCC/toolchain-avr/logs/D20161122.T023341
export MAKE_JOBS=1
  ...
CAPTURELOG build_gcc.configure-host nice make -k -j $MAKE_JOBS configure-host
```

Here is it's execution:

```
+ CAPTURELOG build_gcc.make.configure-host nice make -k -j 1 configure-host
+ log=build_gcc.make.configure-host
+ shift
+ rm -f /g/GNU-GCC/toolchain-avr/logs/D20161122.T023341/build_gcc.make.configure-host.log
+ bash -c nice make -k -j 1 configure-host
+ tee --append /g/GNU-GCC/toolchain-avr/logs/D20161122.T023341/build_gcc.make.configure-host.log
```

Comment: Funny when you write something up and then notice a clue?  Here **nice** is the common element.  *nice* does nothing in MinGW / Cygwin, and editing it out of the bash -c command text seems to solve the problem.